# Isolated scope member updated within link/controller but is undefined when passed to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <main-dir data="data" on-update-map="updateMap(datalength)"></main-dir>
</body>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('mainDir', function () {
    function DatasetDirective() {
        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = "E";
        directive.replace = false;
        directive.scope = {
            data: "=",
            onUpdateMap: "&"
        };
        directive.templateUrl = 'dataset.html';
        directive.controller = function($scope){
          // set "datalength" on scope based on some logic here
          $scope.datalength = $scope.data.length;
          console.log($scope);
        };

        return directive;
    }
    return DatasetDirective();
});
```

dataset.html

```
<div>
    <button ng-click="onUpdateMap()">click me</button>
</div>
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gjQDQ7?p=preview) is here

Basically, I am trying to set a member on the isolate scope of the directive. Then on click of a button within the directive template I am executing a function on the Main Controller containing the directive and passing the member of the isolate scope to the function. I expect "3" to be passed to the function but it evaluates to "undefined"

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in `datalength` from your template as key value pair, basically names of any arguments that you expect should be provided as the key on the directive.

```
<button ng-click="onUpdateMap({datalength:datalength})">click me</button>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TzgDZUjunTE3yKo85iLn?p=preview)**